# How to get height of dynamically created UITextView iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to create a table with cells that contain UITextViews inside them for variable amounts of text.  I need to specify the height of each cell to match the content size of the textviews.  I am using...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITextView *historyNode = [[[UITextView alloc]init]autorelease];
    historyNode.text = (@"%@",[globalArrayWithStrings objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
    NSLog(@"%2.0f",historyNode.frame.size.height);
    return historyNode.contentSize.height;
}
```

For some reason, it always prints 0.  If i print the height of a textview created in interface builder, it prints the correct value.  Any ideas how to get around this or why I can't get the size of a textview until it is added to the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the *sizeWithFont:* method to find the dynamic height. Your *heightForRowAtIndexPath:* should look like this.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *text = [globalArrayWithStrings objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(textViewWidth, 999); // 999 can be any maxmimum height you want
    CGSize newSize = [text sizeWithFont:aFont constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:textViewLineBreakMode];
    return newSize.height;
}
```

Comment: `#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>` at the top of this file to quiet compiler warnings. I think the method ought to resolve without it, but you'll get an unnecessary yellow ! unless you give the compiler a little help.

Comment: What lineBreakMode matches the UITextView behavior?

Answer (score 0):

First set the frame of the uitextView and then you will get the height of the text view.

Comment: But the point is that I don't know what the size of the frame is.  I am trying to get the height of the frame.

Comment: You can calculate the content size of the text as answered by Simon and then you can set the frame of the textview. Then only you can get the height else how can you get the value which you are not setting???